# CentOS 7.5.1804 dnsmasq starts at boot when systemd service dnsmasq is disabled

Tags: centos, samba, dnsmasq

I am configuring SAMBA AD DC using SAMBA_INTERNAL DNS on CentOS 7.5.1804.
For this to work nothing should listen on port *:53/tcp while samba is starting. Something in system starts dnsmasq at boot and blocks port. I can't figure out what is it. Systemd shows that dnsmasq service is disabled:

```
dnsmasq.service - DNS caching server.
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Any ideas how i may locate and disable process which starts dnsmasq?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the process(es) listening on UDP port 53 with `lsof -i <proto>:<port>`:

```
[root@www ~]# lsof -i udp:53
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dnsmasq 4053 dnsmasq    7u  IPv4  52803      0t0  UDP www.example.com:domain
```

Now you have process IDs for dnsmasq. Find out if a systemd service started them, using `systemctl status <pid>`:

```
[root@www ~]# systemctl status 4053
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-11-18 15:48:33 EST; 17h ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           https://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 2881 (libvirtd)
    Tasks: 22 (limit: 32768)
   Memory: 73.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           ├─2881 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
           └─4053 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
```

In my case, libvirtd has started dnsmasq to provide DNS service to virtual machines. Your situation may be different. (Of course, if you do find libvirtd, it means that your architecture is wrong. In this case your Samba DC should be in a VM; the VM host should do nothing but run virtual machines.)

If `systemctl status` gives you no clues, then use `ps` to inspect the command line to see if you can find any further hints.

```
[root@www ~]# ps -l 4053 | cat
F S   UID     PID    PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY        TIME CMD
5 S   968    4053       1  0  80   0 -  6060 x64_sy ?          0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
```

Comment: I've solved this problem on my own, but solution was similar to yours. I've tracked that libvirt is started with the system and it is blocking the port. Thanks for your answer.